# Phpmyadmin not log in (Mac)

Tags: php, mysql, macos, phpmyadmin

I installed phpmyadmin & configured server with this tutorials as per:

http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/installing-phpmyadmin-on-mac-osx-10-7-lion/

I installed and checked server in yesterday and it works fine. But now. cant logged into phpmyadmin.

Showing error :

```
Cannot log in to the MySQL server
```

I created a config file in phpmyadmin root folder...

Is that any issue in coockies..

Anybody please help me..

Comment: Can you log in with your terminal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your mySQL is started:

mysql.server start